# При генерации Java классов из XSD, можно заставить выводить нормальные русские буквы?

Tags: java, xsd

Всем привет.

```
@XmlType(name = "\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0422\u0438\u043f")
```

При генерации Java классов из XSD можно заставить сюда выводить нормальные русские буквы?

Comment: Чем генерируете?

Comment: maven плагином cxf-xjc-plugin

Comment: передаю <arg>-encoding</arg>
                <arg>UTF-8</arg>